# grails-melody plugin Error Failed to resolve dependencies

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to install the grail-melody plugin but I fail to find it.

```
  plugins {
    compile ":grails-melody:1.51.0"
  }
```

This is my BuildConfig

```
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    //mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from pu         
    mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
 ...
   plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.0"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    compile ':jquery-date-time-picker:0.1.0'
    compile ":grails-melody:1.51.0"
```

I get the following:

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.grails.plugins#grails-melody;1.51.0: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


  | Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy   
    for more information):
```

What am I missing please?

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: Which version of grails do you use?

Comment: I've tried to add `compile ":grails-melody:1.51.0"` dependency to the new grails-2.3.5 app, and all works correctly.

Comment: Probably you may had some internet connection problems or temporarily grails plugin central unavailability.

Comment: Also, try to clean project and refresh dependencies `grails clean && rm -rf ./target/ && grails refresh-dependencies`. But last command may not work int the old grails versions.